# Crossfire DAAP Client cannot connect to Firefly

Tags: php, ajax, itunes, daap

Hello Stackoverflow community,  I'm here to ask for a little help.. something I can't seem to work out.

**Problem**: I'm trying to set up a Crossfire Client (A webclient for Firefly (media server)), however when uploaded onto my hosting server, the client can't seem to connect to the  Firefly server.
I've attempted setting up the Crossfire Client on my MAMP(Local server), which connects fine...

**Error Message**:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Timeout)
```

So based on my very limited knowledge, it seems to be a php settings issue (Its the only thing that is possible to be most different) - but I'm not sure what to ask my hosting support, if I'm not 100% sure what the exact problem is.

If anyone could help me out, that would be really appreciated.

More information on [Crossfire Client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmcrossfire/)